# Bootstrap layout problems - no column spacing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to layout a simple dashboard page with a search form at the top. I can't find a way to get column spacing to render as desired. Below is an image of what I have accomplished thus far.

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap Is Hard</a>
        <div id="user">
            <form id="form-login" class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control"></input>
                </div>
                <button id="btn-login" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel-city" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">City</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <select id="sel-city" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt-earch" placeholder="Restaurant name...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
            <div class="col-md-8" style="height: 100%;">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100%;">
                <ul id="list-establishments" class="list-group"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body> <!-- end container -->
```

I would like to have padding around aligned input form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question alone, it's hard to know exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

But based on my understanding, why not add your own `style.css` and put in something like:

```
.form-group {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is a responsive layout with aligned input elements that have spacing between them. To be exact, in the image attached I want spacing between the input elements (i.e. City Select, Search box) and need the City Select to be aligned (i.e. same width as) with the search and map. Sorry for not being more clear.

Comment: For width, simply add a `width: X%` property to the elements that you want to have match up. Regarding vertical padding, my answer above will work fine, just change `padding-right` to `padding-bottom`.

Comment: So in Bootstrap there are no top or bottom margins for rows or columns? That seems a little odd.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the Documentation for [Forms](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#textual-inputs) go, it looks like you need to add the `row` class to your `form-group` while placing your column(s) inside the `form-group/row` div. You shouldn't need a separate row surrounding these now.

**Example Markup:**

```
<div class="form-group row">
```

You should also use the newest Alpha.3 release (if you're not allready) as some issues with forms are now fixed like label padding. [Alpha.3 Release Highlights](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/). And keep in mind that more changes will be coming since this is still in Alpha release.

**Working Example:**

```js
var map;
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {
    lat: -34.397,
    lng: 150.644
  },
  zoom: 8
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 35rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap Is Hard</a>

  <div id="user">
    <form id="form-login" class="form-inline pull-xs-right">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control">
      <button id="btn-login" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</nav>

<div class="container">

  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="sel-city" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">City</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <select id="sel-city" class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt-earch" placeholder="Restaurant name...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
        </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul id="list-establishments" class="list-group"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```